# Show that the solution is unique

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x) = x \sin \pi / x$ where we define $f(0) = 0$.

Show that the differential equation $x'=f(x)$ where $x(t_0)=x_0\ne 0$ has a unique solution, and that the costant solution $0$ is the only solution that satisfies $x(0) = 0$.

---

I do not know how to start with this. Since $f$ is continuos where $x\ne 0$ I know that locally every solution around $(t_0, x_0)$ is unique, but I do not know how to reason what happens when the solution gets extended into $x=0$.